# App store rejection iPhone app for iOS 10.1.1 on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I have updated an iPhone App which was workig perfectly in previously . 
But now after updating Apple has rejected with following issue.

> Performance - 2.4.1
>
> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when
>   reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.1.1. Specifically, the app loads to a
>   white screen and does not displays properly on iPad.
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

I have checked in simulator 10.0 everything looks good .
But i don't have Xcode 8.1 so i can not able to reproduce the issue.

Does any one has any idea about the issue.

Comment: You can download XCode 8.1 and use it apart from your current XCode also fine, in iOS 10 they changed uiview stuff a bit so it might cause some minor problem

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Tj3n . I can download Xcode but i want some instant  solution if you have any let me know.

Comment: You can, but you still need XCode 8.1 to install device support for ios10 (if you have device that run it), so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You should test your app on real device because in some cases some kind of storage techniques work on simulators not on devices.